# Cannot find "validator" and "hinttext" in PlatformTextField in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the flutter_platform_widgets package, in that there is a widget name is PlatformTextField where i cannot find the validator and hinttext options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint can be set via material: (deprecated android:) property:

```
PlatformTextField(
                controller: ...,
                onChanged: ...,
                material: (context, platform) => MaterialTextFieldData(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'textHint')),
              ),
            )
```